# call several functions within same class in hooks

Tags: codeigniter, hook

I need to call several functions from the same class in a hook file.

This is my current code:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'get_info_general',
                                'function' => 'prepare',
                                'filename' => 'get_info_general.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks',
                                'params'   => ''
                                );
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'get_info_general',
                                'function' => 'get_info_general',
                                'filename' => 'get_info_general.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks',
                                'params'   => ''
                                );
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'get_info_general',
                                'function' =>'get_achievements',
                                'filename' => 'get_info_general.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks',
                                'params'   => ''
                                );
```

Unfortunately only the last function `get_achievements` is called. I also tried:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'get_info_general',
                                'function' => 'prepare',
                                'function' => 'get_info_general',
                                'function' => 'get_achievements',
                                'filename' => 'get_info_general.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks',
                                'params'   => ''
                            );
```

But it gives me the same result.

Is there any way to get all three functions to be called correctly, one after another? I didn't find documentation or similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make multidimensional array. From [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html#multiple-calls-to-the-same-hook):

> If want to use the same hook point with more than one script, simply make your array declaration multi-dimensional, like this:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'get_info_general',
    'function' => 'prepare',
    'filename' => 'get_info_general.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'   => ''
);
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'get_info_general',
    'function' => 'get_info_general',
    'filename' => 'get_info_general.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'   => ''
);
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'get_info_general',
    'function' =>'get_achievements',
    'filename' => 'get_info_general.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'   => ''
);
```

> Notice the brackets after each array index:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][]
```